# Running K Kestrel in the background

Tags: linux, macos, asp.net-core

How does one run the Kestrel webserver in a persistent way on Linux / OSX? I am able to run the webserver as expected with:

k kestrel

However, I have not found a way to background it for persistence, i.e.

k kestrel &

The process starts then immediately stops.

Comment: I think there's a env var issue

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. I haven't figured out what's happening yet, but I did notice that I can reproduce the issue in the foreground by redirecting stdin to /dev/null: `k kestrel </dev/null`. This, coupled with the fact that you can't Ctrl+C without first pressing "Enter" twice in the console is suggesting that maybe there's something weird with stdin, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Oh, and you might also try using Docker to run the application in the background. It's a little more involved, but apparently others have had success: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/01/14/running-asp-net-5-applications-in-linux-containers-with-docker.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just try to use

```
nohup k kestrel &
```

Tested with CentOS 7 (64 bit)

Works as expected :)

Comment: as expected...untill server reboot.

Comment: As of year '18 I prefer docker solution. https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/ to be specific. Thanks for answering though !

Answer (score 1):

You can also create **init.d** script which will use s**tart-stop-daemon** together with **nohup** to control your application (not only start in the background, but also stop, autostart at system startup, etc)
Here is [script template](https://gist.github.com/drussilla/3182463b9fa1ec94b9db)
And here are instructions [how to install and configure it](http://druss.co/2015/06/run-kestrel-in-the-background/)

Answer (score 0):

For centos7 you can create systemd wrapper:

File `/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-test.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Web .Net Application running on Centos

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/www/site.tld/htdocs
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /www/site.tld/htdocs/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/asp.net.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=aspnetcoreuser
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, you can manage it via `sudo service kestrel-test start` (stop, status).

Also it works for other systemd OS like Ubuntu16.