# vNext on Apache webserver

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, .net-core

I've been fiddling around with vNext a bit and got the sample projects running. I created an Ubuntu VM, installed the required packages and got it all running with `k run` (console app) and `k kestrel` (MVC app).

Now, onto the next step: running several projects on a dedicated webserver. Kestrel is (at least for now) just a simple development webserver used for vNext. Chances it will develop into a full-blown webserver seem small.

Thus, I would like to get the thing running on Apache. I guess mod-mono would come into play somewhere. However, at the moment I don't think it supports the latest vNext framework yet. On the other hand, I guess we'll need the KRE somewhere.

Any news out there that we'll be running ASP.NET projects on Apache anytime soon? Anyone managed to do it?

I'm greatly fascinated by the idea of cross platform .NET applications. My current employer is investing a great deal in projects using cross-platform and open-source software. I'd like to gain some knowlegde in advance and try to lead the way in migrating completely to Linux web servers instead of Windows servers.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok ... I still haven't found a solution for Apache.
However, nginx is a great alternative to Apache and you can configure it to proxy to the kestrel server:
http://pkula.blogspot.be/2015/01/production-ready-aspnet-5-mvc-vnext-on.html
It's far from perfect but it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

I'm happy to see there are plenty of us trying to get vnext up and running outside Windows environment:)

Of course you are right about kestrel. It will probably end up as a simple web server just like it works right now in the node.js Hello World tutorial. You can try to use it as a production environment by running it in the background [Running K Kestrel in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197571/running-k-kestrel-in-the-background) on a webserver and then pass requests to kestrel by Apache Proxy

VirtualHost example proxying requests to kestrel started on *:5004

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com:80

ProxyRequests On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPreserveHost Off

ProxyPass / http://localhost:5004
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5004

</VirtualHost>
```

But I do not recommend above solution. There are some issue with kestrel that prevents you to send an output outside tty and therefore you can't run it at startup with a startup script. So the website you've started will last as long as your server stays online :)

What I do recommend is to use Docker. It's kind of a wrapper for ASP.NET that is being supported by Microsoft. You could make a better use of that in this stage.

Here's more info

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/01/14/running-asp-net-5-applications-in-linux-containers-with-docker.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how to Docker may help to run Asp.net 5 on Apache. Could you explain more please?

Comment: Hi @Donald I see what you are thinking about. The thing is - you can't run *directly* ASP.NET 5 application under Apache webserver. What you can do is to create an Apache Proxy and pass requests to the Kestrel server. But the recommended solution is to use docker insted. Under the link which I attached you can find a nice tutorial which shows how to make it work under linux environment.

You can also check http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/ which is an OpenSource implementation of .NET if they support 4.6 it's probably possible to run application under Apache